# Code that checks a .txt file, confirms if the word is there and tells you how long the search took

Tags: python, search, time

I'm a complete novice with python and trying to create a piece of code that will ask the user to enter a word, search a text file I have for that word, returns a confirmation on if the entered word is in the file and tells the user how long it took. Here's what I've come up with so far (I know its completely wrong so looking for tips on how I should be writing this rather than someone just giving me a piece of code (I want to learn after all)).

```
import time
import math
import random
import sys

F = open('words.txt','r')
A = raw_input("please enter your word")

for line in F:
     if line == "A":
           print("word is found")
     else:
           print("word not found")
```

Appreciate any help or tips

Comment: Define "completely wrong".

Comment: Keep in mind that every line in the file ends with `'\n'`, so you would need to call `strip()` on it

Answer (score 2):

**1. Ask the user to enter a word**

Seems like you got it right, use `raw_input`

**2. Search my text file for that word**

You will need to look through each line (assumming they are separated by newlines) for that word. Quite simple, I'll cover it later

**3. Returns a confirmation if the entered word has been found**

Just add a print statement to 2.

**4. Tell the user how long the search took.**

For this you would need the `time` module. Compare the time between the start of  the search and the end of the search.

Breaking down the problem into these steps will make it easier for you to come up with the program. You will end up with something like this:

```
import time

f = open("words.txt", "r")

# 1. Ask the user to enter a word
word = raw_input("Please enter your word: ")

# 2. Search my text file for that word
f = open("words.txt", "r")
# 4. Tell the user how long the search took.
start_time = time.time()
for line in f:
    if word in line:
        stop_time = time.time()
        # 3. Returns a confirmation if the word has been found
        print "Word found!"
        break
else:
    stop_time = time.time()
    print "Word not found!"

print "Search took %s seconds" % (str(stop_time - start_time))
```

Now here is my review of your code:

```
F = open('words.txt','r')
A = raw_input("please enter your word")
```

This is not that important but still worth pointing out, try and keep your variable names lowercase unless they are constants.

```
if line == "A":
```

What you probably meant here was `if line == A:`. Please note that adding quotes to a variable name makes python think it's not referring to a variable.

```
print("word is found")
```

Try not to use parentheses when `print`ing in Python 2. This may confuse people to think that you may be using Python 3 (which you are not since you are using `raw_input`).

Lastly, most of your code isn't properly indented. [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) recommends indentation to spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Use "if word in line"

for line in f:
...  if word in line

To mesure time, use time.time()
Call it once at the beginning and call it again after have found the word and calculate the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

read the entire file once, and check if the string is inside

```
user_input = raw_input("please enter your word")
if user_input in open('words.txt','r').read():
```

Use time.time to calculate start and end time, and print the end-start time

```
import datetime   
start_time = time.time()

end_time = time.time()
print "Process time:"   + str(end_time-start_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some Extra... 
If you'd like to search for more than one word, use this:

```
import time #import... (other libraries if needed)

#The program running start time
startTime = time.time()

#Asking the user for a list of words to search over the txt file
userInput = input("Please enter the world you're looking for: ")
#"Converting" the input into a list
wordL = list(map(str, userInput.split()))

#Printing the original user list of words
print("Your Original List is: ", wordL)

existWords=[]
#Searching the user words in the txt file
existWords=[word for word in wordL if word in open('check.txt','r').read()]
#Printing the words that were found
print ("The words that were found in the TXT are: ", existWords)

#The program running end time
endTime=time.time()

print("Program process time: ", endTime-startTime)
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

```
import time
filename = raw_input("Enter filename: ")
target = raw_input("Enter search query: ")
t1 = time.clock()
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
found = target in data
t2 = time.clock()
elapsed = int(round((t2 - t1) / 1000.0))
if found:
    print "Search query found!"
    print "Within", elapsed, "ms"
else:
    print "Search query not found!"
    print "Within", elapsed, "ms"
```

Comment: Please, try to make your answers explainative, not just code

Comment: @Cosinux there are a few inefficiencies and inaccurate readings. 1. You are storing the whole file data into a variable, this means that Python will be using up memory to store the data in the text file. The program will be slow if the file is big. 2. You are timing the total time needed to store the data and search. You should only time the `found = target in data`.